# Need persistence.xml property tag to set sybase database driver version

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink, sybase

I am looking for property tag in `persistence.xml` which will set the Sybase database driver version.

We are using eclipse link to interact with database.

Code snippet below helps us in setting driver version.

```
SybDriver sybDriver = (SybDriver)Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
sybDriver.setVersion(com.sybase.jdbcx.SybDriver.VERSION_605); 
DriverManager.registerDriver(sybDriver);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at definition of `JDBC_PROPERTY` ([link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html#JDBC_PROPERTY)) in EclipseLink as it simply:

> Allows passing of JDBC driver specific connection properties. This allows for properties to be set on the JDBC connection. The JDBC driver specific property name should be appended to this prefix.

you can also find its sample usage there.

*TL;DR:*

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver"/>
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.property.version" value="6.05"/>
```